# Ограничения универсального типа

Tags: c#

[Был взят за основу код из ответа на SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26973999/7663131).
Нужна была доработка класса `MessageHandlerAdapter`, чтобы в качестве базового типа была команда `ICommand<IMessage>`, но при попытке собрать `MessageHandlerAdapter<ICommandHandler<MyMessage>>` получаю ошибку, о том, что мой тип не подходит под ограничения.

```
var handler = typeof(MessageAdapter<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(ICommand<>).MakeGenericType(typeof(MyMessage)));
```

Сами типы:

```
public interface IMessage { }

public class MyMessage : IMessage {};

public interface ICommand<TMessage> where TMessage : IMessage {};

public class MessageAdapter<TMessageCommand> where TMessageCommand : ICommand<IMessage> { }
```

**Вопрос:** почему это происходит и как решить эту проблему? Ведь MyMessage наследует IMessage.

---

Зачем мне это нужно:
Над классом handler будет висеть кастомный атрибут с параметрами команды. Для варианта как у автора на SO нельзя узнать тип, который скрывается внутри лямбды, пока не вызовешь. [Мой полный код.](https://pastebin.com/SAa5bAcW)

Comment: ...ну и при чем тут autofac?

Comment: Скорее этот вопрос нужно задать отдельно. Не так давно начал знакомиться с DI и autofac. Изначально хотел убрать MesssageAdapter, но мне не удалось зарегистрировать  типы в автофак так чтобы получить список IEnumerable<ICommand<IMessage>>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что наследование `MyMessage` от `IMessage` не делает вашу команду `ICommand<MyMessage>` наследницей `ICommand<IMessage>`! В этом можно убедиться вот таким простым кодом:

```
ICommand<MyMessage> foo = null;
ICommand<IMessage> bar = foo; // Ошибка компиляции
```

Для того чтобы `ICommand<MyMessage>` можно было приводить к типу `ICommand<IMessage>` - нужно сделать интерфейс `ICommand<>` ковариантынм:

```
public interface ICommand<out TMessage> where TMessage : IMessage {};
```

К сожалению, на ковариантные интерфейсы наложены сильные ограничения, и для команды такой вариант скорее всего не подойдет. В таком случае придется делать ваш `MessageAdapter` знающим не только тип команды, но и тип сообщения:

```
public class MessageAdapter<TMessage, TCommand> 
    where TMessage : IMessage
    where TCommand : ICommand<TMessage> { }
```